# Sharing data between directives using attributes instead of services

Tags: angularjs, attributes, angularjs-directive

I wanted to make a directive that would essentially act like a specialized input field.  After some logic & user input, the 'value' attribute would be populated with a string of comma separated timeslots (hh:mm).

```
<time-slot value=""></time-slot>
```

becomes

```
<time-slot value="01:00,02:00,03:00"></time-slot>
```

I'd like to provide the flexibility for anyone to place a scope reference in the 'value' attribute tag  -- whenever the attribute value is updated, so is the scope reference.  (In the code below, myModel.times would be in the MyController scope).

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <time-slot value="{{ myModel.times }}"></time-slot>
</div>
```

I have had no problems accessing the 'value' attribute in the  directive.  **However, I have not achieved two-way binding -- myModel.times never captures the changed value,** even though the contents of the attribute have been changed when I inspect the element during runtime.  I am using $attrs.$set to alter the value attribute.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something conceptually, or just missing some extra syntax.  To keep this directive modular and shareable, I don't want to use a service to share data between the controller and directive, nor do I want to use a cascading scope.  I think it would be optimal if the value attribute can simply be referenced by a scope variable and used as desired, much like a simple input tag:

```
<input ng-model="model.someText"></input>
```

Comment: I don't know it it's possible to achieve it this way - perhaps $attrs.$set simply overwrites the attribute value an deletes the interpolation {{ myModel.times }}. But could you use a directive with isolated scope and two-way data-binding between a controller scope and this isolated scope?

Comment: In the directive, I think you are using the `@` scope instead of the `=` scope - hence the two binding does not work - You have not posted the code for your directive so I can only make assumptions...

Comment: I realized that my code is probably executing the way Esa has stipulated.  What is the major difference between using @ and = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with two-way data binding: See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/33YhJVZig89KgNUjTNAq).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('timeSlots', function() {        
    return {
      scope: { value: '=' },          
      link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
        // you can access $scope.value here (after it has been interpolated)
      }
    };  
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 42;
  }]);
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <time-slots value="value"></time-slots>      
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.  I was at first wondering if the controller scope variable name had to be 'value' since the directive scope refers to value:

    scope: { value: '=' },

But 'value' here is referencing the attribute name, not the scope variable.  So yes, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for.